# Is it a bad idea to save/process a file in a Custom Model Binder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I am trying to figure out the best way to handle a file upload for my model.

I have an object in my entity layer that has a filename field to store information about an uploaded file that is saved to the file system. I do not want to create a property on my object for HttpPostedFileBase.

Typically, I would add another parameter to my action for the uploaded file and then manually copy it to my object. However, all of this happens in my controller after the default model binding has taken place.

I am thinking that I could create a custom model binder that processes the upload stream, resizes the image and saves it to the drive. It will then set the property of the object to have the correct filename.

Does this seem like a bad practice? Any better ideas? I do not really want to setup a ViewModel just for this postback as all of my data annotations are on my entity object.

Comment: Any reason you can't do that in the action method itself? A custom model binder MAY BE a good choice if you need this behavior in more than one place

Comment: I can. However, if I have a required attribute on my model, when the default model binding happens, it will flag that upload (filename) field as missing when in reality it just hasn't been processed yet.